# on Kotlin exists other way to set array data?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, optimization

I would like to know if it is the optimal way to set values on a array

```
fun setParameters(myArray: MutableList<Symbol>, instance: MutationData){ 

    myArray.forEachIndexed { index, valArr ->
            myArray[index] = setValues(valArr, members?.settings)
            myArray[index] = setValueForByReference(instance, myArray[index])
        }
}
```

or if exist a better way as create another array and fill into and after return the new array I don't know what do you think?

learn if I did right with this solution or get a optimal way to solve

Comment: What are `setValues` and `setValueForByReference`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do to your array. You mention a "new" array, but you have not created a new array above--you only changed the contents of the existing array.

Comment: @Joffrey are function that apply transformation to he value array for example:
input --> "hellow i am charles"
output --> "Hello, I'm Charles"

Comment: @Tenfour04 right now I'm not creating a new array, I'm editing myArray inside forEachIndexed, I would like know if is better or not create two arrays and apply on the second one transformation that come of use setValues or setValuesByReferences on the first one. or if exists other way.

Comment: So `setValues` doesn't set anything, right? It transforms one value and returns the result? This naming is really super confusing to me. Also you're writing twice to the same index, so the first time could just be a local variable it seems. I don't get why you're using the array for this.

Comment: @Joffrey sure applay a transformation, sorry by naming is a little confuse to me to because I have to optimize that existing code, and smells bad. the trouble is that is mutate or transforms several data

Comment: Oh, I just saw your edit. Arrays and lists are quite different beasts. It turns out you're actually using a list, not an array here

Comment: @Joffrey I'm so sorry yes is a Mutable List, but the var was called myArray :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you need to create a copy or not depends on all the surrounding code and how the array is used. It is actually somewhat rare in practice to use arrays at all. You should default to using List unless you are working in code that needs to be highly optimized or you need something that is mutable but with fixed size.

Your current code modifies the existing array. If this is what you need, it could be simplified slightly by avoiding the array write and extra array read with the intermediate value:

```
myArray.forEachIndexed { index, valArr ->
    val interimValue = setValues(valArr, members?.settings)
    myArray[index] = setValueForByReference(instance, interimValue)
}
```

If you don't need to modify the array, so a copy is OK, you can use the `map` function. But it returns a List, not an Array. Like I said above, you usually should prefer working with Lists anyway. `map` makes this a bit easier because you don't have to deal with the `index`.

```
val newList = myArray.map { valArr ->
    val interimValue = setValues(valArr, members?.settings)
    setValueForByReference(instance, interimValue)
}
```

---

Edit based on your update and comment:

`forEachIndexed()` is already quite optimized. I would maybe pull out the `?.settings` property call so you aren't doing it repeatedly:

```
val settings = members?.settings
myArray.forEachIndexed { index, valArr ->
    val interimValue = setValues(valArr, settings)
    myArray[index] = setValueForByReference(instance, interimValue)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, sorry for the inconveniences above I updated to share the complete function, and you are right myArray is a mutableList passed by reference, on this mutable list could contain several Symbols to be mutate and normalize use #instance# parameter inside the setValueForByReference, so I need optimized this to handle a considerable amount of data.

Comment: @Cpereira1 I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`mapIndexed`**

```
myArray.mapIndexed { index, valArr ->
        setValues(valArr, members?.settings)
        setValueForByReference(instance, myArray[index])
    }
```

Comment: I have to check, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes. Please do let me know if this worked.

Comment: This doesn't match the original behavior. You are calculating and then releasing the intermediate result, and the second result is calculated from the original value instead of the intermediate result.

Comment: thanks dude but use mapIndexed doen't works because myArray is passed by reference, I updated above the function to be more a little more accuracy